# Update flatpak from the command line?

Tags: command-line, flatpak

What is a command line equivalent to sudo apt-get update or sudo snap refresh for flatpak?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The command

```
flatpak update
```

essentially will update any flatpak packages on the system. There is no need to use "sudo".